# Issue finding number of occurrences of a given substring in a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

The below code always returns number of matching sub strings as zero.There are no errors in the code and i am not sure where have i gone wrong logically.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{ 
    int i,j,len ,k ,count, num ;
    char str[100],sub[100],comp[100] ; 
    // sub is the sub string .
    printf("Please enter the string") ; 
    gets(str) ;
    printf("Enter the substring to be searched for") ;
    gets(sub) ;
    len=strlen(sub) ;
    for ( i=0 ; i < strlen(str) - len ; i++ ) 
    //Goes till length of string - length of sub string so that all characters can be compared.
      {  
         num = i + len ;
         for ( j=i,k=0 ; j<num ; j++, k++ )
         //Loop to store each sub string in an array comp.
           {
             comp[k]=str[j] ;
           }
         if ( strcmp(comp,sub) == 0 )
            { count++ ; }
     }
    printf("no of occurances is:%d",count) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Why do you need to make a copy of the sub string in the first place?

Comment: use fgets instead of gets unless there is a very good reason.

Comment: Use a debugger or at least print the data you check.

Comment: @ForeverStudent: Which reason would rectify to use an unsafe function with not more features?

Comment: @Olaf: stupid ones we all heard before: fgets not allowed by assignment, fgets not supported by our custom compiler/runtime, etc

Comment: @ForeverStudent: `fgets` is C standard, `gets` is **not**. Without specific details, we have to assume standard C, which is C11 (C99 is most times acceptable, too). Call me strict, but any of those "reasons" you gave are even beyond "stupid". As I just had a question about Yoda conditions, I tend to call them Jaja-reasons.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, when constructing `comp`, you're not adding a terminating null byte at the end.  Because the rest of `comp` is not initialized, you invoke undefined behavior when calling `strcmp`.

Add the null byte at the end of the inner `for` loop will fix the problem:

```
     for ( j=i,k=0 ; j<num ; j++, k++ )
     //Loop to store each sub string in an array comp.
       {
         comp[k]=str[j] ;
       }
     comp[k] = '\0';
```

Actually, rather than creating a separate substring, just use `strncmp`, which compares up to a certain number of characters:

```
for ( i=0 ; i < strlen(str) - len ; i++ ) 
//Goes till length of string - length of sub string so that all characters can be compared.
  {  
     if ( strncmp(&str[i],sub,strlen(sub)) == 0 )
        { count++ ; }
 }
```

Also, don't use `gets`, as that is prone to buffer overflows.  Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Note: As the compare will not exceed the length of the strings, code code use `memcmp(&str[i], sub, ...)`   Likely faster with long strings  YMMV.

Comment: That was very helpful for a beginner like me man. Thank you !

Comment: @RahulMayuranath Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: After making the above changes( using fgets instead of gets and adding a terimal null byte) I am now getting an output digit in excess of 30000 for every test case. What is happening ?

Comment: @RahulMayuranath We would need to see the code.  Please post that as a separate question.

Comment: @dbush [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069399/find-number-of-sub-strings-in-a-string) **I posted it as a separate question. **

Answer (score 0):

- Try changing your for loop from this :

  ```
  for ( i=0 ; i < strlen(str) - len ; i++ )
  ```

  to

  ```
  for ( i=0 ; i <= strlen(str) - len ; i++ )
  ```