# fgets() not scanning the number of strings I want

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, fgets

I have an array of sentences and I want to scan them first with `fgets()` and then print them one by one. Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>





int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    char sentence[100][100]; /* 100 sentences with at most 100 characters*/
    int n,i,j;

    scanf("%d",&n); /* number of sentences*/

    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        fgets(sentence[i],100,stdin);
    }
    printf("****************************");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<strlen(sentence[i]);j++) {
            putchar(sentence[i][j]);
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that this only scans n-1 sentences. Why is that?

And the other weird thing is that after printing the asterisks, it starts printing at a new line without me telling it to do so.

Comment: yes, because `fgets()` considers the newline as a part of the input.

Comment: To avoid this issue entirely, never use `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the input is

```
3
abc
def
ghi
```

The cursor stays after the number `3` on the first line after n is scanned.

You can add a space after `%d`, like `scanf("%d ", &n);` to move the cursor to the next line. (This assumes that the first sentence does not start with spaces).

Depends on whether your environment is (Windows / Unix), and whether you want every string to keep the end of line character, you need to increase the buffer size to:

- 101 - for Unix line ending and you are fine to discard the end of line character for sentences of 100 characters long
- 102 - for Windows line ending and you are fine to discard the end of line character for sentences of 100 characters long
- 102 - for Unix line ending and you want to keep the end of line character for all sentences
- 103 - for Windows line ending and you want to keep the end of line character for all sentences

For example, if you incorrectly used 101 for Windows, for the following input

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

The output would be:

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789


0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789


0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

(there are some empty lines)

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! But what exactly has the cursor position have to do with how many strings are read?

Comment: The first `fgets` will read an empty string because it sees an end of line character immediately. So `sentence[0]` will be `"\n"`. Then the first sentence will go to `sentence[1]` etc. The 100th sentence would not be read. (You can imagine fgets as pressing Shift+End and then move to the next line)

Comment: Rather "So `sentence[0]` will be `"\n"`"

Comment: You would also want to increase the size of the buffer to something like 102 if your sentences are at most 100 characters long.

Comment: @TonyWong why 102? and Please extend your answer to cover the second issue in the question also. :)

Answer (score 1):

Both the cases will be solved by one concept, [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) considers a `newline` as a part of the input.

*Issue 1:*

You have a `newline` left in the input buffer (due to the ENTER key press after the first input) which is picked up by the immediate next `fgets()`.

*Resolve issue 1:*

Use

```
  scanf("%d%*c",&n);   //simple solution
```

or

```
 scanf("%d",&n);
 while (getchar() != '\n');  //eat up anything upto newline
```

to clear the trailing newline.

*Issue 2:*

`fgets()` scans and stores the `newline` as a per of the input. If you don't want the newline as a part of the input, you've to check and remove that manually.

Related quote from the man page:

> [...] If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. [...]

*Resolve issue 2:*

```
  sentence[strcspn(sentence, "\r\n")] = 0;
```

<sup>Thanks to [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux), more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2173917)</sup>

Comment: Now consider [hacker exploit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069399/find-number-of-sub-strings-in-a-string/35069527#comment57862941_35069527) vs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2410359

Comment: @chux Thank you once again for noticing these minor but very relevant details and leaving the comments!! It's people like you who defines the perfection. Appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the man page for fgets?

fgets() ***reads in at most one less than size characters*** from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

So your code should be, as pointed out by chux :

```
fgets(sentence[i],sizeof sentence[i],stdin);
```

Comment: This is wrong advice. "So your code should be `fgets(sentence[i],101,stdin);`.  "The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n` ..."

Comment: `sentence[i]` is an array of 100 `char`.  `fgets(sentence[i],101,stdin);` allows `fgets()` to read 100 characters _and_ attempt to save the appended `'\0'` resulting in UB.  Better to use `fgets(sentence[i], sizeof sentence[i],stdin)`

Comment: @chux would strlen works as well? sizeof does work now because the size in bytes of char is 1, right?

Comment: `fgets(sentence[i], strlen(sentence[i]),stdin)` would not work well.  When `fgets()` is called, the prior contents of `sentence[i]` are not defined - and irrelevant to the read operation.  We need to pass the size of the array.

Comment: @chux thank you, I didn't know that. I appreciate that you have learned me something! LSNED